# How does Android volume control work?

Tags: android, volume

For example, when you use the Volume rocker to raise the volume, a volume adjuster appears without interfering with the ongoing activity. I will able to continue playing a game for example, without it pausing and still have the ability to increase the volume. I am talking about this volume control https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF2fW.jpg

Anyone know how this is achieved? Source code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Volume Control might be implemented as a fragment. Since fragment has its on own life cycle it will not interfere with the life cycle of the underlying activity.